# Is "their futures" acceptable?

Tags: grammatical-number, adverb-position

Is the following phrase grammatically correct? I am confused about the position of the adverb *successfully* and if the term *future* can be pluralized.

> . . . successfully prepare all students for their futures

Comment: The phrase is perfect, with each word ideally placed and inflected. Whether you need the adverb *successfully* (which seems redundant) or can upgrade the Latinate *prepare* to the Saxon *ready,* is another question. Good luck.

Comment: The question title doesn't appear to be related to the question body.

Comment: Well, @MariusHancu's answer probably supersedes my comment. Thanks, Marius. Good point.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong about it. It is preferred as:

*'successfully prepare all students for their futur**e**'*

In such contexts, "future" is considered by the large majority as uncountable and singular, even though it relates to a multitude of people.

At Google Books (do NOT use vanilla Google):

["prepare them for their **future**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prepare%20all%20students%20for%20their%20futures%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22prepare%20them%20for%20their%20future%22)
About 29,100 results

["prepare them for their futures"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prepare%20all%20students%20for%20their%20futures%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22prepare%20them%20for%20their%20futures%22)
About 304 results

**Thus the plural is used by some authors trying to emphasize that those futures are separated, individual, but that is quite unusual (about 100 to 1!).**

Comment: I like your technique. I am curious: can one apply the technique to this question? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/237679/25823

Comment: Although only 25% of the first 40 results in your "prepare them for their future" search were appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's nothing apparently wrong about it. Maybe the context might make your doubts more clear.

Also, this has nothing to do with American English *versus* British English.

I agree with Marius that the plural "futures" does sound a bit odd. I didn't think anything of it, though, because there are multiple students. I don't think it would make a significant difference either way.